# actualizar jTable en jFrame desde otro jFrame

Tags: jframe, jtable, singleton

soy nuevo y no tengo experiencia pero estoy comenzando a crear mi aplicación de consulta, tengo un jframe donde muestro un jtable con el resultado de una consulta, al hacer click en una linea del jtable guardo en una variable el dato a buscar y mostrarlo en otro jtable que se encuentra en otro jframe que se abre al hacer click, la pregunta es: puedo actualizar el segundo jtable con el nuevo dato al hacer click ?

codigo al hacer click en mi primer jtable:

```
private void jTablaMuestraArticulosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                    
     int column = 0;
     int row = jTablaMuestraArticulos.getSelectedRow();
     value = jTablaMuestraArticulos.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString();

            ConsultaCantidad cCantidad = new ConsultaCantidad();
            cCantidad.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println(value); 
    }
```

El jframe ConsultaCantidad se abre y me muestra el resultado de otra consulta que tengo en un metodo.

```
   private void ejecutaConsultaSTOCK2(){
            cc = new Conectar();
            cn = cc.getConnection();

           try{
        String sql2= "SELECT CLAVE,V_DEPOSITOS.nom_dep as DEPOSITO, CANTI as CANTIDAD "
                   +"from qdepo Inner join NOMDEP v_depositos  On v_depositos.COD_DEP=qdepo.depo "
                   +"where CODARTI ='01"+ConsultaStock.value+"'  and canti > 0 order by depo";
            s1 = cn.createStatement();
            rs = s1.executeQuery(sql2);
            ResultSetMetaData rsMd2= rs.getMetaData();
            int numeroColumnas = rsMd2.getColumnCount();
            DefaultTableModel modelo1 = new DefaultTableModel();
            this.jTablaCantidad.setModel(modelo1);

            for (int x = 1; x <=numeroColumnas; x++) {
                modelo1.addColumn(rsMd2.getColumnLabel(x));
            }

           while    (rs.next()){
               Object [] fila = new Object[numeroColumnas];
               for (int y = 0; y <numeroColumnas; y++) {
                   fila [y]=rs.getObject(y+1);
               }
               modelo1.addRow(fila);

               jTablaCantidad.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(0,0);
           }

            s1.close();
        int numfila = modelo1.getRowCount();
        if (numfila==0) {

            System.out.println("no hay datos para mostrar");

        }
        }

           catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);

        }
   }
```

El problema me surge cuando le doy nuevamente click al primer frame y me vuelve a abrir otro jframe con el resultado, he probado con el metodo singleton pero no me actualiza los datos del jtable, necesito que no me abra otro jframe, necesito que solo actualice los datos del jtable.

Desde ya muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

si creas un metodo, y cuando hagas el click lo vuelves a llamar...

```
        Object value = Tabla_analisis.getValueAt(row, column);
        if (value instanceof JButton) {
            ((JButton) value).doClick();
            JButton boton = (JButton) value;
```